# Show attribute instead of fid in QField form

Tags: qgis, qfield

I collect data of tree species per sample plot using QGIS and QField.

Plots (Provyta below) is a point layer with a relation many to one to a table with data of all tree species found at the plot.

Once data is collected and I click the point, go to tab Data which is the referenced table, see first screenshot below.

The 5 and 6 is the fid of each species, I would like it to display the species name instead (Tall, Gran). And just above, where it says 3 (which is the plot fid) I would also like to choose some plot attribute instead. Is this possible?

I cant figure out how, there is no such option in the Form layout of the plots?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must go to the layer properties and choose the right attribute for **Display** option. You can use an Expression if you want to show more than one

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use the Display function with a small expression as Nelson mentioned.

[image]

in combination with labeling

[image]

It looks like this

[image: Labels next to the trees]

[image: Display features/tree species + circonference]